# Can't send file through Jmeter

Tags: file, jmeter, upload

I am a new user of JMeter and I would be very glad if you could help me. I've been stuck with sending file with JMeter.

I'm trying to send request with following settings:

[HTTP Request. Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNffR.png)

[HTTP Request. Files Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gbNw.png)

[HTTP Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXYSW.png)

Here is the request:
Headers:

```
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=Jmeter
auth-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Length: 888859
Host: host_address
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/1.8.0_231)
```

Body:

```
PUT http: host/mobile/trainings/531/tasks/2709/solutions/33254

PUT data:
--RsttCxvdTM00rKCR1_vSX-3Q8lqQfe9w017Tb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file[]"; filename="answer_to_videoselfy.mp4"
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--RsttCxvdTM00rKCR1_vSX-3Q8lqQfe9w017Tb--


[no cookies]
```

In response I've got:

```
{"ok":false,"message":"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"}
```

What interesting is that I can upload this file using Postman. Also I tried to import postman curl to JMeter and it still doesn't work.

The curl from Postman:

```
curl -X PUT \
  http://HOST/api/v1.0/mobile/trainings/531/tasks/2709/solutions/33235 \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: 888848' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: HOST.com:8000' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 88be-621bbfdc5f7d,ba4f2182-1083-4c37-92c0-906052b5a6ef' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.20.1' \
  -H 'auth-token: b36a8d4c5c7:69d5625e4f72f1171c1549e3f8cb8439' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -F file=@/C:/Users/user/Documents/answer_to_videoselfy.mp4
```

Any suggestions what should I do in JMeter to make it work?

p.s. I tried to add 'Content-Length: 888848' to HTTP Header Manager but it didn't help

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove `Content-Type` header from the [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
2. Change "Parameter Name" in the "Files Upload" section to `file`
3. Either copy `answer_to_videoselfy.mp4` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation or change the "File Path" to be `C:/Users/user/Documents/answer_to_videoselfy.mp4`

---

In general given you're able to execute the request in Postman you should be able to record it using JMeter

1. Prepare JMeter for recording, the easiest way is using [JMeter Templates](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature/) feature

   - from JMeter's main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Open [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and click "Start"

   [image]
2. Prepare Postman for recording

   - from Postman main menu choose `File - Settings - Proxy`
   - tick both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` and provide `127.0.0.1` as the "Proxy Server" and `8888` as the proxy port:

   [image]
3. **Copy `answer_to_videoselfy.mp4` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation**
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter should create the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)
6. [Parameterize or correlate](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) this `auth_token` and you should be good to go

Comment: thanks! I have this additional header in Content type :P I removed and it works